# Three.js : WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: width != height for cube map

Tags: javascript, three.js

> Error:**WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: width != height for cube map**

here is part of my codes:

```
var path = "/Content/wallerpaper/";
            var format = '.jpg';
            var urls = [
                path + '1' + format, path + '2' + format,
                path + '3' + format, path + '4' + format,
                path + '5' + format, path + '6' + format
            ];

            var textureCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls, THREE.CubeRefractionMapping);

            textureCube.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;

            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, envMap: textureCube, refractionRatio: 0.95 } );
```

How to solve it **without** change my images size?

Comment: You don't. Your graphics card doesn't support it.

Comment: @Kenney thanks guy,but I am confused for "Graphics card not support",can u explain some details about the reason?

Comment: Graphics cards have some limitations on texture dimensions. Ususally width and height must be a power of 2 (1024, 2058 etc), but _some_ cards support different sizes. In this case, the textures must all have the same sizes, and the same width and height. You can only make a cube using 6 equal sized squares. There's no way around this except to rescale the images (and you could do this in code, by stretching/cropping), but it's easiest to just fix the textures.

Comment: 2058 is not power of two !